# how to build a form whose fields which include select and textarea fit in a row using JS and Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I've been trying many fronts to get these fields to fit in a row, but no success and I'd appreciate some help.

The fields are built using JS as the user clicks on a button.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<div id="new-content-form-horizontal">
  <div id="form-fields" class="row justify-content-around space-evenly">
    <form id="form" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="select-wrap"><label for="monthSelect">Month</label>
          <select id="monthSelect">
            <option value="January">January</option>
            <option value="TBD">TBD</option>
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="select-wrap"><label for="statusSelect">Status</label>
          <select id="statusSelect">
            <option value="3. Uploading To Site">3. Uploading To Site</option>
            <option value="4. Published">4. Published</option>
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="select-wrap"><label for="title">Title</label><textarea id="myTextarea" class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="select-wrap"><label for="main-kw">Main KW</label><textarea id="main-kw" class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="select-wrap"><label for="typeSelect">Page Type</label>
          <select id="typeSelect">
            <option value="Home">Home</option>
            <option value="Services Page">Services Page</option>
            <option value="Local Landing Page">Local Landing Page</option>
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="select-wrap"><label for="new-rewrite">New or Rewrite</label>
          <select id="new-rewrite">
            <option value="New">New</option>
            <option value="Rewrite">Rewrite</option>
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="select-wrap"><label for="notes">Notes</label><textarea id="notes" class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="select-wrap"><label for="content-draft">Content Draft</label><textarea id="content-draft" class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="select-wrap"><label for="final-url">Final URL</label><textarea id="final-url" class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```